# Is there a way of initializing a codeigniter 4 Model variable once in a Controller

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, model, controller, codeigniter-4

I understand that we could autoload or load models in the constructor and use them all through the class in earlier versions of codeigniter like below:

```
//Declaring the variable

$this->load->model('model_name');

//Using it through the controller

$this->model_name->function();
```

But in codeigniter 4, is there an easier way of defining a model variable once in a Controller. The current way i know of doing that is :

```
//Declaring the variable

$model_var = new ModelName();

//Using it through the controller

 ????????
```

But as far as i have tried looking, i have to do the initializing in every function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is create a property for the controller to hold an instance of the model.

CI v4 relies on an initializer function instead of a constructor to set up properties and the like. So creating something like this would follow "best practice" for a simple controller in a simple app.

````
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

/**
 * Class SomeController
 *
 */

use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var ModelName instance
     */
     // $modelVar; ```edited - will throw a php syntax error```

     protected $modelVar; ```this works```

    /**
     * Initializer 
     */
    public function initController(\CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface $request, \CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface $response, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {

        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);

        // Load the model
        $this->modelVar = new ModelName();
    }

}
````

For your convenience, CI supplies `/app/Controllers/BaseController.php` that the above example used in part.

The idea behind `BaseController` was to provide a class that could be used to load resources (classes, helpers, etc) that EVERY controller in the application would need. Then each controller would extend from `BaseController`. The above example assumes that there isn't a need for anything else, which in real-life is unrealistic. So the above could extend `BaseController` too if there were a need.

Comment: I had a syntax error in my code until i used `protected $modelVar` then everything worked well.

Comment: Oops. I forgot the access modifier. Now fixed.